# LINQ syntax is giving error in razor page

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have written a LINQ syntax inside my .cshtml page using razor syntax though it is working fine but .net compiler is giving following error

My Syntax is

@String.Join(" - ", item.Apps.Select(t => t.AppName))

and the error is like this

Error   CS1061  'List' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no accessible extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'List' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Why it is throwing error.I have tried to set some configuration in web.cofig file but not working.

Thanks

Utpal Maity

Comment: I'm not sure about the syntax, but you need some `@using System.Linq`.

Comment: At the top of the view I have written @using System.Linq;

Comment: Can you specify the item type is a custom `List` class or the standard  [System.Collection.Generic.List](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1)?

Comment: It is a custom list

Comment: If you want use the [Enumarable.Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select), then the class need to implement the interface [IEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1).

Comment: Does putting `.ToList()` before the `.Select()` work?